# Connection not private error even after uninstalling Fiddler

Tags: proxy, fiddler

I installed Filler few days ago and now that I dont need it, I uninstalled it. But after uninstalling it, I get "Connection not private error" when I try to access some https gitlab pages. I am totally stuck and no clue how to to get rid of this issue. If I install Fiddler again, and enable "Capture" under it, I can again start accessing the https pages. But, when I uninstall it again, I am back to the same problem of "Connection not private" error. How do I get rid of this issue after uninstalling Fiddler?

Until I figure this out, I am forced to keep Fiddler installed (as a workaround) which I dont like. Any ideas?

Update: The error is the typical error you get with https pages when you cant access it, when you click on advanced it says:

"gitlab normally uses encryption to protect your information. When Google Chrome tried to connect to gitlab this time, the website sent back unusual and incorrect credentials. This may happen when an attacker is trying to pretend to be gitlab, or a Wi-Fi sign-in screen has interrupted the connection. Your information is still secure because Google Chrome stopped the connection before any data was exchanged."

Comment: What's the actual error? (click Details)

Comment: Its the usual connection not private error you see on chrome, I updated my question

Comment: Do you mean `NET::ERR_SSL_PINNED_KEY_NOT_IN_CERT_CHAIN`?

Comment: I see this error - NET::ERR_CERT_WEAK_SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM